# CkEditor 5: Toolbar not responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm trying to get the toolbar to be responsive, like the example on https://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-5-v15.0.0-with-horizontal-line-page-break-responsive-toolbar-and-SVG-upload-support/.

My CkEditor plugins are all version 19.0.0. I'm using a custom build, based on the classic editor.

But the result I get is [image]

Can someone help please? The doc is telling this must should happen automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

set this "shouldNotGroupWhenFull" true and use '/' or  '-' to make a line break and render items in multiple lines in toolbar

```
const config = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [ 'bold', 'italic', '|', 'undo', 'redo', '-', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList' ],
        shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
    }
};
```